# Event listener when another event changes my input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, listener, jquery-events

I have an input with datepicker class on it, which looks like this:

```
<input class="ui-calendar hasDatepicker" type="text" name="date" id="date">
```

I need to cover all scenarios when this input value is changed. So I have a .datepicker onSelect (used when I select the date via datepicker calendar) and simple onChange (used when I enter the date by keyboard) events:

```
$('#date').datepicker({
  onSelect: function() {
    console.log('datepicker onSelect event');
  }
});
```

and

```
$('#date').on('change', function() {
  console.log('onChange event');
});
```

Now the problem is that I have separate button:

```
<a href="#" onclick="setDate('date', '2018-12-05', '2018-12-05'); return false;">Set date</a>
```

And this setDate function changes the value of my datepicker input.

How do I catch this setDate event without putting any code into setDate function itself? I tried adding listener on my datepicker input but it only catches values I enter by keyboard.

Comment: Just listen on `input` event `$('#date').on('input', function() {
  console.log('onChange event');
});`

Comment: _“Now the problem is that I have separate button”_ - and you only need this in this one specific place? Then I’d simply modify the `onclick` handler of that very button here … call setDate, trigger a change event on $('#date'), return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `on*` event attributes, attach your event handlers unobtrusively.

Secondly, you should make `setDate()` change the date through the `datepicker()` library, then you'll get this behaviour for free:

```
<a href="#" class="set-date" date-foo="date" date-date1="2018-12-05" data-date2="2018-12-05">Set date</a>
```

```
$('.set-date').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#date").datepicker("setDate", $(this).data('date1'));
});
```

Alternatively you can set the `val()` on the input and manually `trigger()` a `change` event.

```
$('.set-date').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#date').val($(this).data('date1')).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Yeah, .trigger could be a way out, but is there any way without editing the setDate function itself? It runs on entire project and I need this very trigger only on one case in separate page.

Comment: Yes, the methods I've shown will work without you amending the `onclick` reference, it's just a much better idea if you do.

Comment: Problem is that I can't even edit the href button class itself... So I can't put the set-date class on it. Solved this by adding onClick event on a tag like this: $('.form-field .ui-calendar').parent().on('click', 'a', function()

Thank you for your answer!